# print the minimum length of the subarray you can choose to make A and B same after performing the operation in c language

Tags: minimum

`#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);                                    // Reading input from STDIN
printf("Input number is %d.\n", num);       // Writing output to STDOUT
}
`

print the minimum length of the subarray you can choose to make  A and   B same after performing the operation.